# Students who see ears of another student

Tags: combinatorics, extremal-combinatorics

A student is standing in each cell of an $n\times n$ grid, looking at one of the four directions: up, down, left, right. It turns out that no student is at the border and looking out of the grid, and no student directly sees the face of another student (every student sees either the ear or the back of another student.) What is the minimum number of student who sees the ear?

I think we can achieve $n+4$ with this configuration, shown for $n=5$. (The arrows show which way the students are facing.)

$$\begin{matrix}
\downarrow&\downarrow&\downarrow&\downarrow&\downarrow\\
\downarrow&\downarrow&\downarrow&\downarrow&\downarrow\\
\downarrow&\downarrow&\downarrow&\downarrow&\downarrow\\
\downarrow&\downarrow&\downarrow&\rightarrow&\downarrow\\
\rightarrow&\rightarrow&\rightarrow&\uparrow&\leftarrow
\end{matrix}$$

Comment: I agree that you can definitely generalize that pattern and get $n+4$. Just add a row of ↓ along the top and column of ↓ the left side, except one → in the bottom left corner, and repeat.

Comment: Note that for small $n$, you will need a modification:  for $n = 2$, the minimum is obviously $4$; a simple enumeration for $n = 3$ should give a minimum of $6$, not $7$.  I actually think that the minimum is $n + 3$, not $n + 4$.

Comment: This is nicely connected with the Borsuk-Ulam theorem.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The minimum is $n+2$, with the construction in chubakueno's comment.

Proof that this is minimal:

Split the students into lines (maximal subsets of students in a straight line all looking the same direction).

The last student in each line must be looking at an ear (in fact, the number of lines equals the number of students looking at an ear).

Each line has at most $n-1$ students.

Thus there are at least $\lceil \frac{n^2}{n-1} \rceil = n+2$ lines, and thus at least this many students looking at an ear.

An illustration (slight modification of chubakueno's comment):

$$\begin{matrix}
\downarrow&\downarrow&\downarrow&\downarrow&\leftarrow\\
\downarrow&\downarrow&\downarrow&\downarrow&\uparrow\\
\downarrow&\downarrow&\downarrow&\downarrow&\uparrow\\
\downarrow&\downarrow&\downarrow&\downarrow&\uparrow\\
\rightarrow&\rightarrow&\rightarrow&\rightarrow&\uparrow
\end{matrix}$$

You see $n+1$ lines each with the maximum $n-1$ elements, plus one lonely student in a line of one element (upper right).

Comment: Very elegant and direct. I was still doing the details for a convoluted induction proof that, more generally, $m\times n$ needs $\min\{m,n\}+2$. Using your nice line-counting argument, this generalized result also follows at once: If wlog. $m\ge n\ge 2$, then each line has at most $m-1$ students and from $(m-1)(n+1)<mn$ we see that at leat $n+2$ lines are needed (and as dropping columns from the left in your illustration shows, $n+2$ lines suffice).

Comment: @HagenvonEitzen Thanks. The rectangular case $m > n$ is interesting. Your counting inequality doesn't work, unfortunately. Instead, some more analysis of what's going on is needed: Either each of the $n$ columns contains a vertical line, or there's one with $m$ horizontal lines (then, since there can't only be horizontal lines, at least $m+1 \geq n+2$). So now consider the case with (at least) $n$ vertical lines. Each column contains a horizontal line necessarily. So to have only $n+1$ we'd need these all to line up, but that's impossible. So we do get $n+2$.

Answer (score 2):

Consider a slight modification of your arrangement:  $$\begin{matrix}
\downarrow&\downarrow&\downarrow&\downarrow&\downarrow\\
\downarrow&\downarrow&\downarrow&\downarrow&\downarrow\\
\downarrow&\downarrow&\downarrow&\downarrow&\color{red}\downarrow\\
\color{red}\downarrow&\color{red}\downarrow&\color{red}\downarrow&\color{red}\downarrow&\color{red}\leftarrow\\
\rightarrow&\rightarrow&\rightarrow&\color{red}\rightarrow&\color{red}\uparrow
\end{matrix}$$
which looks better to me, and in the general case, gives $n+3$ as the number of students who see the side of another student's face for $n \ge 3$, and for $n = 2$, the minimum is obviously $4$.

Comment: Also, a possible regular(ish) arrangement: $$\begin{matrix}
\downarrow&\leftarrow&\leftarrow&\leftarrow&\leftarrow\\
\downarrow&\downarrow&\downarrow&\downarrow&\uparrow\\
\downarrow&\downarrow&\downarrow&\downarrow&\uparrow\\
\downarrow&\downarrow&\downarrow&\downarrow&\uparrow\\
\rightarrow&\rightarrow&\rightarrow&\rightarrow&\uparrow
\end{matrix}$$

Comment: @chubakueno: Yours is better: you’re getting only $n+2$.

Comment: @BrianM.Scott Interesting, it also works with $n=2$! So now we have the bound $n\le f(n) \le n+2$ in the general case, a proof doesn't seem very far away...